# My JavaScript volume slider is not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is little issue with My volume button and Volume Slider it's not functioning. So,i am looking for help for fixed this.

code as follows:

```
var audio,  mutebtn,  volumeslider, seeking=false, seekto;
```

function initAudioPlayer(){
    audio = document.getElementById("myTune");

```
// Set object references
mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider");
// Add Event Handling

mutebtn.addEventListener("click", mute);
seekslider.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){ seeking=true; seek(event); });

volumeslider.addEventListener("mousemove", setvolume);
// Functions

function mute(){
    if(audio.muted){
        audio.muted = false;
        mutebtn.style.background = "url(http://iflixweb.stream/radio.co-player/spk.png) no-repeat";
    } else {
        audio.muted = true;
        mutebtn.style.background = "url(http://iflixweb.stream/radio.co-player/mute.png) no-repeat";
    }
}
function seek(event){
    if(seeking){
        seekslider.value = event.clientX - seekslider.offsetLeft;
        seekto = audio.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
        audio.currentTime = seekto;
    }
  }
function setvolume(){
    audio.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
  }
```

}
  window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: codepen link: https://codepen.io/iflix/pen/WXwxqg

Comment: volume slider and mute button not working

Comment: Have you looked at the error console. There's a typo in your code throwing an error. `TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function. (In 'document.getElementbyId("myTune")', 'document.getElementbyId' is undefined)`

Comment: @Mark_M how do is fixed this.tried many times? not work...

Comment: `document.getElementbyId` should be `document.getElementById` [notice the caps]

Comment: where? i didn't get the location?

Comment: `seekslider` is `undefined`

Comment: @ImeshUmayanga Welcome to [SO]! Please include a [mcve], so we understand where you're coming from, and so future readers benefit. Include the smallest, sample (with full HTML, CSS, and JS) to reproduce the issue. BTW, there's a button in the post editor to include codepen-style code directly inside a post, and to run it inline (or, access it with Ctrl+M).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part:

```
audio = new Audio();
```

into:

```
audio = document.getElementById("myTune");
```

Also, your seekslider is undefined, so for now, you can comment those lines until you implement it.

```
// seekslider.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){ seeking=true; seek(event); });
// seekslider.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){ seek(event); });
// seekslider.addEventListener("mouseup",function(){ seeking=false; });
```

Here is a functional codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmKLge

EDIT: Comment out line 11 from your new code pen.

```
//seekslider.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){ seeking=true; seek(event); });
```

For your mute volume to work like you want, add

```
function setvolume(){
        audio.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
        if (!audio.volume) {
            mutebtn.style.background = "url(http://iflixweb.stream/radio.co-player/mute.png) no-repeat";
        } else {
        mutebtn.style.background = "url(http://iflixweb.stream/radio.co-player/spk.png) no-repeat";
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!,mute work now.but slider not work. code pen: https://codepen.io/iflix/pen/WXwxqg

Comment: Which browser are you using? This codepen seems functional on Chrome. Also, make sure you deal with `seekslider` being undefined.

Comment: Comment out the line 11 from your new codepen. `seekslider` is undefined.

Comment: can you edit on codepen..seems not work for me.i am using opera.test chrome too,i am using windows 10

Comment: one last thing,How  should i changed the code to,when seek bar value is 0 for display mute button

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ftk5fam8/2/ I also edited my answer

Comment: Thanks!,My friend.work everything as needed

Comment: I have still little issue, The stop button function,that i used, still mention -i have connect with streaming.so, how i completely disconnect from stream by clicking stop button.. can you update the code in yours or mine:  https://codepen.io/iflix/pen/pdyazj